# Wrap multiple modules in single Module Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-components

I have a component library having around 20 modules. I want to wrap them up into a single service and export so that it can be globally injected. When I do this and inject it into app.module.ts, the features are not able to find the component.

My CoreComponentModule with all other modules look like this.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { BreadcrumbModule } from './core/breadcrumb';
import { ButtonModule } from './core/button';
import { CheckboxModule } from './core/checkbox';
import { ChipsModule } from './core/chips';
import { DatepickerModule } from './core/datepicker';
import { ErrorMessagesModule } from './core/error-messages';
import { HeaderModule } from './core/header';
import { IconModule } from './core/icon';
import { InputModule } from './core/input';
import { MultiselectModule } from './core/multiselect';
import { ProgressSpinnerModule } from './core/progress-spinner';
import { RadioButtonModule } from './core/radio-button';
import { SelectModule } from './core/select';
import { SideNavModule } from './core/side-nav';
import { SlideToggleModule } from './core/slide-toggle';
import { SliderModule } from './core/slider';
import { TooltipModule } from './core/tooltip';
import { WizardModule } from './core/wizard';

const CORE_COMPONENT_MODULES = [
  CommonModule,
  BreadcrumbModule,
  ButtonModule,
  CheckboxModule,
  ChipsModule,
  DatepickerModule,
  ErrorMessagesModule,
  HeaderModule,
  IconModule,
  InputModule,
  MultiselectModule,
  ProgressSpinnerModule,
  RadioButtonModule,
  SelectModule,
  SideNavModule,
  SlideToggleModule,
  TooltipModule,
  WizardModule
]

@NgModule({
  imports: CORE_COMPONENT_MODULES,
  exports: CORE_COMPONENT_MODULES,
})
export class CoreComponentModule { }
```

I also have a feature module which consist of all the different features as shown below:-

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {LoginModule} from './auth';
import {DashboardModule} from './dashboard';
import {CoreComponentModule} from '../components';
@NgModule({
    imports:[
        CoreComponentModule,
        LoginModule,
        DashboardModule
    ],
    exports:[
        LoginModule,
        DashboardModule
    ]
})

export class ViewModule{

}
```

At last the app.module looks like the following:-

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { CoreComponentModule } from './components';
import { ViewModule } from './views;

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreComponentModule,
    ViewModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am not able to understand why this throws error regarding the components as well as I am not able to use any component. Am I over wrapping the components.
I tool reference/inspiration from Angular 2 Material git repo. Please direct me if I have done something wrong.

The Error That I am getting is as follows:-

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'app-breadcrumb' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-breadcrumb' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-breadcrumb' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<p>
  login works!
  [ERROR ->]<app-breadcrumb></app-breadcrumb>
</p>
"): LoginComponent@2:2 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: SyntaxError__zone_symbol__error: Error: Template parse errors:
'app-breadcrumb' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-breadcrumb' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-breadcrumb' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<p>
  login works!
  [ERROR ->]<app-breadcrumb></app-breadcrumb>
</p>
"): LoginComponent@2:2
    at SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:96291:33)
    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:73328:16)
    at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6048:16)
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:20378:19)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:53611:68)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:53494:62
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:53494:19)
    at createResult (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:53376:19)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:95722:26)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:95593:43)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:96015:57
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:95755:35)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:95631:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:95913:35)__zone_symbol__message: "Template parse errors:↵'app-breadcrumb' is not a known element:↵1. If 'app-breadcrumb' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.↵2. If 'app-breadcrumb' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<p>↵  login works!↵  [ERROR ->]<app-breadcrumb></app-breadcrumb>↵</p>↵"): LoginComponent@2:2"__zone_symbol__stack: "Error: Template parse errors:↵'app-breadcrumb' is not a known element:↵1. If 'app-breadcrumb' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.↵2. If 'app-breadcrumb' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<p>↵  login works!↵  [ERROR ->]<app-breadcrumb></app-breadcrumb>↵</p>↵"): LoginComponent@2:2↵    at SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:96291:33)↵    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:73328:16)↵    at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6048:16)↵    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:20378:19)↵    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:53611:68)↵    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:53494:62↵    at Set.forEach (native)↵    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:53494:19)↵    at createResult (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:53376:19)↵    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:95722:26)↵    at Zone.run (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:95593:43)↵    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:96015:57↵    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:95755:35)↵    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:95631:47)↵    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:95913:35)"_nativeError: ZoneAwareErrormessage: (...)get message: ()set message: (value)name: (...)get name: ()set name: (value)originalStack: (...)get originalStack: ()set originalStack: (value)stack: (...)get stack: ()set stack: (value)toSource: ()toString: ()zoneAwareStack: (...)get zoneAwareStack: ()set zoneAwareStack: (value)__proto__: BaseError Error: Template parse errors:
'app-breadcrumb' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-breadcrumb' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-breadcrumb' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<p>
  login works!
  [ERROR ->]<app-breadcrumb></app-breadcrumb>
</p>
"): LoginComponent@2:2
    at SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:96291:33)
    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:73328:16)
    at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6048:16)
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:20378:19)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:53611:68)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:53494:62
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:53494:19)
    at createResult (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:53376:19)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:95722:26)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:95593:43)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:96015:57
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:95755:35)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:95631:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:95913:35)
consoleError @ zone.js:420
_loop_1 @ zone.js:449
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:453
```

Sample Breadcrumb component:-

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BreadcrumbComponent } from './breadcrumb.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    BreadcrumbComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    BreadcrumbComponent
  ]
})
export class BreadcrumbModule { }
```

Image for the Folder Structure and each component being a module
[image]

Comment: "why this throws error" if you get an error it would be quite helpful to see the exact error message

Comment: If the code above is an indication of any issues, you have a syntax problem in the app.module. You are missing a single quote where you import the ViewModule. Doubtful that will fix all of this for you, though.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I updated the stack trace for the same.

Comment: The breadcrumb component is exported in the module that contains it?

Comment: @R.Richards I guess that happened while pasting the code. Basically I want a all components(which are themselves a module) to be wrapped into a common module and export out. I want to do the same with features as well.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have updated the Breadcrumb module. Hope that helps?

Comment: If you add the `Breadcrumb` component to `exports: [...]` directly instead of the extracted array, do you get a different error message?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer have to check that out. But can that be an issue?

Comment: Unlikely, just simplifying to locate the error. I assume you checked that the `Breadcrumb` components selector is `'app-breadcrumb'`?

Comment: yes indeed it is app-breadcrumb @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Are you using it in `ViewModule` or any other module than `AppModule` or `BreadCrumbModule`?

Comment: Let me explain. I have made one module called `breadcrumb.module` which is wrapped in a `corecomponent.module` which is injected to `app.module`. On the other hand all feature based components are wrapped in  in `ViewModule` and I inject this as import in `app.module` @GünterZöchbauer does it make sense ? And basically I want to make my component modules Globally Available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components can't be made available globally.

Every module where components, directives, or pipes are used need to have the module that provides these listed in `imports: []`

It is not enough to import them in `AppModule` only.

Comment: Cool. This does work. Now its clear. So components are basic building blocks and can be imported wherever required. Nice.... Another thing is if something is required globally then in such case what should be done?

Comment: No, components can't be imported wherever required. A component is declared in exactly one `@NgModule()` and every module that wants to use that component needs to import that module. That's all there is.

Comment: Just wanted to ask Whether Angular Material does that. Do they have a mechanism or they too work in the same fashion. Hope I am not bothering

Comment: They have module per component. https://github.com/angular/material2/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ngmodule&type=Code

Comment: Correct. So even I have the same. I have updated it in the Question as a Pic. I have each component as a module and want to follow the same as they do. Have a look at the Question once please.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem. Do you still get this error message?

Comment: No issues. I dont get the error messages but I wanted the components to be loaded at a global level as for all the views just like the Angular 2 Material does. So that if you import it once in the App Module its available throughout the application and one can use it. Error is resolved but doubt still remains.  :(

Comment: You can't. Material components also need to be imported into every module where one of them is used. You can have a module that export modules like it exports components. This way you can combine feature modules to a bigger feature module, so you need to import only one module to get the components of a set of modules available, but you still need to add at least one import to the module where you want to use anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the point. Now I understand how the application should be structured as a whole. Thanks a lot.

Comment: With most recent Angular versions, you can make Components available globally.